# Unity can't find package installed with Nuget in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, package

I installed some ASP.NET packages (`FirebaseStorage.net` if it matters) via Nuget in my game's project in Visual Studio.

Visual Studio itself shows no errors, as it probably understands `using Firebase.Storage` internally, but when it comes to Unity, it says

> **The type or namespace name 'Firebase' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

I believe this happens because I installed this package through the Nuget Package Manager, inside Visual Studio, and it probably has nothing to do with Unity, so Unity doesn't find it.

How can I make Unity understand packages from Nuget?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use a Nuget package in Unity you have to add it manually.

How you can do this:

- create a separate temporary Visual Studio project
- install the Nuget package
- copy the dll's from the temporary project to a "plugins" folder in the Assets folder of Unity.
- Unity now builds the project with the dll's of the Nuget package
- However, now comes the hard part of having to do it manually: if the dll has dependencies on other dll's, these will also have to be added manually. That is the big advantage of Nuget package manager.

Comment: Isn't the Nuget Package manager for Unity deprecated?  Are there no other tools for this?  Thanks!